# Laravel redirects to login after authentication

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

### PROBLEM

I'm busy with my first Laravel app and although I see the benefits of the way things are written, I'm having a hard time understanding some of the behaviour.

When I try to login I get redirected to the login page. It seems like the user authenticates correctly, but it redirects to the login page regardless.

### WHAT I HAVE

My users table looks like this:

```
,---------,---------------,---------------,----------------,---------------,-----------,
| user_id | user_username | user_password | user_firtsname | user_lastname | user_type |
|---------|---------------|---------------|----------------|---------------|-----------|
| 1       | me@domain.com | encrypted     | Foo            | Bar           | farmer    |
'---------'---------------'---------------'----------------'---------------'-----------'
```

This is my routes file:

```
<?php
Route::get('/login', 'UsersController@login');

Auth::routes();
Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@dashboard')->name('dashboard');
Route::get('/users/grid', 'UsersController@grid');
Route::resource('/users', 'UsersController');
```

LoginController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function username()
    {
        return 'user_username';
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector
     */
    public function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        return $user->user_type === 'farmer' ? redirect('/dashboard') : redirect('/admin');
    }
}
```

User.php

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_username', 'user_firstname', 'user_lastname', 'user_password',
    ];

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'user_password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * @return mixed|string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->user_password;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getKey()
    {
        return $this->user_id;
    }
}
```

### WHAT I'VE DONE

I've read various [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45191677/laravel-5-4-redirect-after-authentication) [on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35499929/laravel-5-redirecting-to-login-page-after-authentication-instead-of-dashboard) [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42177044/laravel-5-4-redirection-to-custom-url-after-login) but for some reason I can't get login to work.

I created the auth using `php artisan make:auth`. I've tried reading the documentation too, but still no luck.

### QUESTION

How do I get it to redirect to the dashboard after login? What am I missing?

Comment: you have to change `user_password` field to `password`. Because some of the methods in laravel using hard coded `password` field as password. You firstly change that then It will work.

Comment: I would prefer to not change the password field in the db. Is there some way that I can perhaps alter it before it goes through all the laravel code?

Comment: you have to override those functions in LoginController with change `password` field to `user_password` field

Comment: Which functions are these? If you could maybe point me in the right direction. Also, it doesn't make sense, because if I put a `dd($user)` in the `authenticated` call in my `LoginController`, it does show the authenticated user.

Answer (score 2):

> You need to add this prop in your user model.

```
protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
```

> Remove the `authenticated()` method from login controller.

***And handle the redirection based on user type inside `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware***

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
          if (Auth::guard($guard)->user->user_type === 'farmer'){
            redirect('/dashboard'); // make sure the urls is correct with condition above 
          }
          return redirect('/admin');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

> ***Extra step inside `App\Exceptions\Handler` class***

***Add this method if you have different login pages for each user type***

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @param AuthenticationException $exception
 * @return JsonResponse|RedirectResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }
    if ($request->is('dashboard') || $request->is('dashboard/*')) {
        return redirect()->guest('/dashboard/login');
    }

    return redirect()->guest('farmer/login');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem yesterday night. I have found that the issue is Auth::attempt() does not persist the login so when a user is logged in successfully, it was dropped in the session after redirect to /home.

Below link provided the answer to solve it:
[Laravel Auth:attempt() will not persist login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21603347/laravel-authattempt-will-not-persist-login)

> Try to add something like
>
> `protected $primaryKey = 'user_id'; in class User{}`
>
> (app/models/User.php)
>
> (Field user_id is auto increment key in my Schema for 'users' table)

Answer (score -1):

You are using `user_password` field instead of `password` field. So you need to do some changes in `LoginController.php` file. Below is the updated `LoginController`. Try to do changes like this and then try to login

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function username()
    {
        return 'user_username';
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector
     */
    public function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        return $user->user_type === 'farmer' ? redirect('/dashboard') : redirect('/admin');
    }

    /**
     * Validate the user login request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return void
     */
    protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            $this->username() => 'required|string',
            'user_password' => 'required|string',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only($this->username(), 'user_password');
    }
}
```

I added two functions `validateLogin` and `credentials` where default field was `password`. and I changed this with `user_password`.

Comment: This doesn't work. My login view file, has `password` as the input field. My `User.php` has an accessor for password that authenticates against my db field, `user_password`. Like I said in my comment, if I `dd($user)` in my `authenticated` function, it returns the authenticated user, it just doesn't redirect.

Answer (score -1):

for authentication in laravel first use `php artisan make:auth` command

and in your web.php add `Auth::routes();`  only which have all authentication  routes

and to check if you are login or not you should add   `$this->middleware('auth');` in constructor of controller like

```
 public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
```

and do not forget to call auth class like  `use Auth;`

or you can check authentication  in your routes by add middleware auth

and also check https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication  documentaion