# Why is a login via `auth guard A` redirected different than one from `auth guard B` when the same behaviour is expected?

Tags: php, multi-tenant, laravel-6

First of all, i'm not a pro in PHP development or Laravel but will try to explain my question as well as possible for me. I also try to give enough information but when something is missing, please let me know whats missing and i will add it!

Some important context about my project:

- Laravel 6.18 (will update soon if my first goal is reached)
- I use Hyn/Multi-tenant to make my application mutli tenant.
- I use a Vue front end, i give a `bearer token` to Vue via the `app.js`

The application should be a multi tenant application where each tenant has its own user table. I first built everything as "single tenant". When the basic functionality was implemented and worked fine, i added Hyn/MT to make it multi tenant, moved the tenant specific tables to the tenant db folder and updated the models. Now i know it was better to start with Hyn/MT before building all the functionality but so far i got everything working fine.

After i added the multi tenant support to my project and fixed the broken functionality i decided to add an admin specific area to manage the tenants. To achieve this i added a `SystemU ser` table to the `master` database which contains the admin users. After that i update my `web.php` so it gives the subdomain to the `LoginController.guard()` function. My code:

```
// web.php
  Route::group(array('domain' => '{subdomain}.festipay.xlan'), function () {
    Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
  });


// LoginController.php

  protected function guard()
  {
    if (Request::route("subdomain") == "admin") {
      return Auth::guard('admin_web');
    } else {
      return Auth::guard('web');
    }
  }
```

I also updated my `config/auth.php`, it looks like this now:

```
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin_web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admin_users',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

         'admin_users' => [
             'driver' => 'eloquent',
             'model' => App\SystemUser::class,
         ]
    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],
```

Except for the mentoined changes i did not implement any admin specific logic yet. So i expect that the admin users are handeled exactly the same except for the way they are authenticated.

The tenant users who log in to e.g. `tenant_x.domain.com` are redirected to `/dashboard` when they login and are redirected back to `/login` when they log out. The admin users who log in to `admin.domain.com` are not redirected to `/dashboard` when the login is successfull but are redirected back to `/login` again. Offcourse this is not the expected behaviour as it should be (currenly) the same as the tenant users (so a redirect to `/dasboard` when the login is succesfull)

I think that the authentication them selve works fine as the `LoginController.attemptLogin()` returns `true` when i use valid admin credentials and `false` (and view shows wrong credetials) when i use invalid credentials.

I found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52799922/laravel-redirects-to-login-after-authentication) that is may be a session issue and i tried to apply the solution mentoined in that post. Unfortunately did adding `protected $primaryKey = 'id';` to the `SystemUser` class not solve the issue. I also compared the tenant `User` class with the `SystemUser` class but they are almost identical exccept for unimportant fields i removed from the `SystemUser` like address.

I have no idea how i can find out where the issue occurs or how to solve this. The goal is that an admin which logged in succesfully is redirect to another page as the `/dashboard`. Can someone help me find out what goes wrong? i'm already happy when someone can help me to get the same behaviour for the admin's as the tenants currently have.

Thanks in advance!

---

**Update 1 @David Barker**

When its about the session, i think this is important to know as well:

`- I use a Vue front end, i give a` bearer token`to Vue via the`app.js``

My session config:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
return [
    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),
    'expire_on_close' => false,
        'encrypt' => false,
    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
    'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION', null),
    'table' => 'sessions',
    'store' => env('SESSION_STORE', null),
    'lottery' => [2, 100],
    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),
    'http_only' => true,
    'same_site' => null,
];
```

I did a `dd($request->session();)` in the `LoginController->attemptLogin();` function, see the result bellow. The result is the same for both users except for the `id` and `_token`. (i cleaned the cookies before the login attempt in both cases)

```
Illuminate\Session\Store {#490 ▼
  #id: "7WI7JUWPnS4pg3EHvaxk5TOKaM9l9UXJi1zJNKuG"
  #name: "festipay_session"
  #attributes: array:1 [▼
    "_token" => "mtMWanYGMUxFHivOqAaEmVQnHDE0hvwKkHMgCswg"
  ]
  #handler: Illuminate\Session\FileSessionHandler {#489 ▼
    #files: Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem {#198}
    #path: "/var/www/domain.com/storage/framework/sessions"
    #minutes: "120"
  }
  #started: true
}
```

Maybe this is also interesting infomation. Left are the responses for the admin (after i clicked the `login` button) and right the working tenant login.

[image]

Comment: This is most likely a session issue, more importantly the validity of the session cookie that Laravel sets. Can you post your session config in your question please.

Comment: @DavidBarker I updated my question. I also read something about Laravel session's but i was still not able to solve the issue. Hope you can help me out.

Comment: What is the `SESSION_DOMAIN` env variable set to on your different environments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the issue. It was very easy to solve. I did not specify the `auth guard` for the `Route::group`.

It was like this:

```
  Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

    Route::get('/', function () { return redirect('/dashboard'); });
    Route::get('/dashboard', function () { return view('dashboard'); })->name('dashboard');
    Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name
```

I changed it to this to make it work:

```
  Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:system_user_web,web'], function () {

    Route::get('/', function () { return redirect('/dashboard'); });
    Route::get('/dashboard', function () { return view('dashboard'); })->name('dashboard');
    Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name
```